# module service is not available injecting service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/AmuC4CpfMnP9ySmOI54C?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['extraService']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'extraService', function ($scope,$http,extraService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
}]);

app.service('extraService',function(){
  return 'abc';
});
```

What's wrong with my service injection? Why am I getting module service extaService is not available error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to inject service `extraService` when declaring module

use

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
```

instead of

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['extraService']);
```

Comment: it worked but why when I console.log(extraService) I'm seeing an empty object instead of abc?